# asp.net mvc set parent element class from ActionLink helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, menu

I have the following menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
<li class="nav-header">Navigation Menu</li>
<li>@Html.MenuLink("Test Link", "Index", "Home", "active",true)</li>
```

MenuLink is a helper that sets a class to the ActionLink (href) element:

```
public static HtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string activeClass, bool checkAction)
        {
            string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

            if (string.Compare(controllerName, currentController, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 && ((!checkAction) || string.Compare(actionName, currentAction, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
            {
                return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, null, new { @class = activeClass });
            }

            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);

        }
```

What I need is to set the class attribute to the parent HTML element, in this case the `<li>` element, so the final result would be:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
<li class="nav-header">Navigation Menu</li>
<li class="active"><href="....."></li>
```

instead of the actual result:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
<li class="nav-header">Navigation Menu</li>
<li><href="....."  class="active"></li>
```

Any clue, any advise is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: the MvcSiteMap would make this easier and give you the flexibility of styling menu items and headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the MenuLink helper you can simply use the @Url helper like this:

```
<li class="active">
    <href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
</li>
```

and write your custom Helper only to generate the result for class name (e.g. active )

so the final code would look something like this:

```
<li class="@Html.YourCustomHelperForActiveTab("Index","Home")" >
    <href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
</li>
```

UPDATE: it might also be helpful to some people to mention that an example helper for getting the class for each tab could be like this: [(Source)](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/asp-net-mvc-helper-for-active-tab-in-tab-menu)

```
public static string ActiveTab(this HtmlHelper helper, string activeController, string[] activeActions, string cssClass)
{
    string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.Controller.
            ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();
    string currentController = helper.ViewContext.Controller.
            ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();

    string cssClassToUse = currentController == activeController 
         && activeActions.Contains(currentAction)
                               ? cssClass
                               : string.Empty;
    return cssClassToUse;
}
```